# How do I configure the Android 4.0+ emulator to behave as a tablet?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-virtual-device

I have been developing Android application for Android 3.x and now I want to support Android 4.0.

So I created a new AVD from AVD Manager with a target of Android 4.0.3 and API Level 15, resolution 1280 x 800.

The emulator runs normally, but its UI is in phone mode, not tablet, and my app (for tablets) UI is collapsed.  i.e., notification bar sets top, not bottom.

How do I make the emulator recognize that it should run as a tablet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use your tablet skin. For example `WXGA` (default skin for 3.x). You can change skin via AVD manager. Or by command line. For example to run device `name`:

```
[me@pc]# emulator @name -skin WXGA
```

The skin must be supported. You can find skins in `[SDK]/platforms/<platform-name>/skins`.

Comment: I did not find WXGA in android 4.0

Comment: @Nishant, You can use another one, e.g: `WXGA800`, `WXGA720`... I have those all in `android-15/skins`.

Comment: means 4.0 does not supports tablet screen

Comment: @Nishant Yes it does  :-). I don't have 4.0, but 4.0.3. And I can run 4.0.3 with tablet skin.

Comment: which skin you have selected for tablet in 4.0.3

Comment: @Nishant, I find them in the directory I mentioned. I used `WXGA800`. You can try some of them.

Comment: @hai bison, WXGA800 opens the emulator in 480 x 800 but I want to open it in 1280 x 800.

Comment: @Nishant Sorry I can't help you. Because I called `emulator @my_device -skin WXGA800` and it worked on my machine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9461/discussion-between-nishant-and-hai-bison)

Answer (score 3):

Android Emulator detects automatically in which mode to run.
As I see, the main criteria is resolution and, maybe, screen density.

That's how I've created Asus Transformer emulator:

- AVD Manager -> New... -> Skin, select "Resolution" -> 1280x800
- Hardware Properties: Abstracted LCD Density set to 160 (actually, Transofrmer's one is 149).

After I run it, I've got Tablet UI!